# Slow down a computer "second" to get more CPU cycles to screen capture real time animations

Tags: cpu, performance, screen-capture, animation

I'm on Linux and I want to do video screen captures in 4k of realtime (in the common sense, not kernel realtime) generated animations such as demos from the demoscene or stuff from `shadertoy.com`.

Since I'm doing it in a 4k resolution at 60fps this is quite resource intensive (or even higher resolutions and framerates). Add the video capture task and my computer is not fast enough anymore.

Since there is no user interaction it wouldn't matter if a four minute video took 40 minutes to process and record but that should guarantee me a steady and uninterrupted animation with 60 frames per seconds (or whatever I desire).

Can I artificially slow down what a "second" means? So that I get more real CPU cycles per second. From the inside of the animation and capturing process anything would look the same except the CPU, in the example above, is up to 10 times faster (4min vs 40min). The resulting video file, once the system returns to normal, will play normally then.

Comment: On Linux you might be able to artificially limit the resources available for a demo. For your idea to work you have to assume that the demos are actually running on a timer rather than just a loop that gets as fast as it gets. In addition every system service etc. would have to act accordingly. Limiting the process resources could be an approach that yields more results.